# ML-Yacc Tiger Parser not properly parsing lvalue

Tags: parsing, yacc, tiger, ml-yacc

I'm working on the parser component of my [Tiger compiler](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/) in SML using ML-Yacc. I cannot find any glaring problems with my grammar file (I've used priority rules to resolve all shift-reduce conflicts) but it seems to never reduce using the second and third rules of `lvalue`, which I've specified as follows:

```
lvalue : ID                       ()
       | lvalue DOT ID            ()
       | lvalue LBRACK exp RBRACK ()
```

The grammar for `exp` is:

```
exp : lvalue                      ()
    | INT                         ()
    | ID LBRACK exp RBRACK OF exp ()
    | lvalue ASSIGN exp           ()
    ...
```

When trying to parse `a[0] := 5`, I expect it to reduce using the fourth `exp` rule (where the `lvalue` is `lvalue LBRACK exp RBRACK`). Instead, Yacc finds a syntax error and substitutes `ASSIGN` for `OF` and parses using the third `exp` rule.

Similar problems occur with `lvalue DOT ID`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as I was typing the question up, so I'll answer my question in case anybody else runs into this problem.

<s>The issue (I think) is that the grammar for `lvalue` is left-recursive. I thought Yacc might throw a warning about it, but it didn't - maybe the precedence rules I set hid the problem. Left-factoring the grammar fixed the problem:</s>

edit: Left-factoring just happened to resolve the problem, but left-recursion was not the issue. See comment below and a similar [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968665/bison-shift-reduce-conflict-tiger-compiler/26977277#26977277).

```
lvalue : ID lvalue'                 ()

lvalue' :                           ()
        | DOT ID lvalue'            ()
        | LBRACK exp RBRACK lvalue' ()
```

Comment: Left recursion is not the problem, exactly. Left-recursion is not usually problematic for bottom-up parsers. The problem is the `ID` in `ID LBRACK exp RBRACK OF exp`. If it had been `lvalue LBRACK...`, there would have been no problem. But as written, the parser cannot know whether or not to reduce `ID` to `lvalue`. Appel notes this issue in his textbook (or at least one of the language versions of the textbook) and I discuss some possible solutions with `bison` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977277/1566221) (starting with the paragraph "The shift/reduce conflict in state 1...")

Comment: @rici After making my response I started to doubt whether left recursion could actually be the problem. Thank you for the clarification - I considered editing the OP to ask about it but wasn't sure how much visibility it would get.